# Why is the content of the User Menu in English and not the current language?

Tags: joomla-3.x, language

I am using Joomla 3 and have just added the user menu to my web pages. The user menu contains 3 items and all are in English.

What do I have to do to get them to display in German (the front-end language)?

Comment: Menu items will show whatever text you enter. So, how have you managed your other menu items so far? The same applies for the User menu. I guess you didn't create these User menu items and you are using the ones that get created with the installation of the sample content. But easily you can go in Menus and edit them.

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought it was some kind of system module like the login form where the texts are all translated. Now I know what to do :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu items will show whatever text you enter. So, how have you managed your other menu items so far? The same applies for the User menu.

I guess you didn't create these User menu items and you are using the ones that get created with the installation of the sample content. But easily you can go in Menus and edit them.